# IBM Content Navigator Eclipse issue - Neon

Tags: eclipse, ibm-content-navigator

Has anyone tried to use eclipse neon as the IDE for content navigator development? I have placed com.ibm.ecm.icn.plugin.202.jar and com.ibm.ecm.icn.facet.EDSPlugin.202.jar inside dropins folder and restarted eclipse but no luck. I also tried placing them under eclipse\plugins but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it may be good to point out that you're not using the most current version of the com.ibm.ecm.icn.plugin.jar - a newer version can be obtained at: 
See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=27051e6c-51e8-43b7-936e-d1321912207d&ps=25

Unfortunately obtaining the newer version still won't fix your problem as the plugin depends on some older resources, you can however correct this.

Steps to get it to work with Eclipse **neon3**:

1. Download the 203 version of the plugin (link above);
2. In eclipse: file->new->"Plug-in from Existing JAR-Archives"
3. Choose to include (into the plugin) the .jar file you've just downloaded
4. For the newly created project, fill in the blanks / choose the defaults
5. Replace the contents of the generated MANIFEST.MF with the contents of the jar's original MANIFEST.MF
6. Notice that one of the dependencies/version cannot be resolved (org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.core) remove it, then add choose add to include the current version
7. Export the project as "Deployable plug-ins and fragments" to a folder
8. The folder contains your updated .jar file that goes into your eclipse/plugins directory

*Note that te above is an answer to the ICN plugin, the same steps may also apply to the EDS plugin, but i'm not currently using that one.*

Edit: A modified 2.0.3 for can be found [here](https://www.ivojonker.nl/?p=571).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the source code is in:
https://github.com/ibm-ecm/ibm-content-navigator-samples/tree/master/eclipsePlugin

You can rebuild the plugin as your wish for different eclipse version. For oxygen, there is a little different. The process is in the README.md.